# oleobject alternative c#

Tags: c#, ole, powerbuilder

I need to mimic a part of code in powerbuilder 11.5 to C# 3.0. In powerbuilder the code has oleobject and connects to object using connecttonewobject. Could someone tell me whats the equivalent in C# and what to use here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example using C# dynamic attribute (just like pb object)

```
// get the class id from name
Type myComType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SAP.BAPI");

// equal to connect to ojbect in PB
dynamic myComInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myComType, false);

// calling function equivalent to oleobject.function in PB
myComInstance.ShowDialog("Hello World");
```